# Nested while loop in PHP in getting data from database

Tags: php, sql-server, while-loop

```
<?php
$sqlquerypmenu = "select * 
                    from subsubmenu 
                    where submenu_id=1 
                    and position='left' 
                    and status=1";
if($querypmenu = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlquerypmenu)){
    if(sqlsrv_has_rows($querypmenu) === true){
        while($rowdata = sqlsrv_fetch_array($querypmenu, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
?>                            
<h4 class="title-small folder_name">  <?php echo $rowdata ['website_title'];   ?> </h4>
 <?php
            $id = $rowdata['id']; 
            $filequerymenu = "select * 
                                from upload_files 
                                where main_menu='value_name' 
                                and sub_menu='value_key' 
                                and subsub_menu= $id  ";  
            if($filemenu = sqlsrv_query($conn,$filequerymenu)){
                if(sqlsrv_has_rows($filemenu) === true){ 
                    while($filedata = sqlsrv_fetch_array($filemenu, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){  ?>
<a class="smalltext font_val" href="<?php echo DOCUMENT_URL.$filedata ['file_name'];  ?> "  target="_blank"  ><?php echo $filedata['document_name']; ?></a> 
<?php
                    } 
                } 
            }     
        }
    }
}
?>
```

In the nested *while loop* the second *while loop* only shows the first row of data and does not show the rest of the data.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please use the formatting rules you have available.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: _Small Note_ `sqlsrv_has_rows()` returned a Boolean so you might like to check this line `if(sqlsrv_has_rows($filemenu) >0){ `

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks. I have corrected that part but still it is not giving the required result

Comment: Are you absolutely sure there should be more than one row?

Comment: You're missing the '?>' at the end of the ' SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){  ' line.

Comment: @riggsfolly yesss there are more than one rows in the database

Comment: @C Hunter In my code it was there. I dont know why it was not showing here. I have edited the code above now but still it is not giving the expected results.

Comment: @nishant3 ... does the outer loop run through ALL rows or just the first one as well?

Answer (score 0):

Consider querying the database once with one `JOIN` query. Possibly opening up another fetch within a `while` loop causes instances issues:

```
<?php
...

$sql = "select s.website_title, u.file_name, u.document_name
        from upload_files u
        inner join subsubmenu s ON u.subsub_menu = s.id
        where u.main_menu = 'value_name' 
          and u.sub_menu = 'value_key'
          and s.submenu_id = 1 
          and s.[position] = 'left'
          and s.[status] = 1
        order by s.id, s.website_title;"

$title = "";

if($result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql)){
    if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result) === true){
        while($rowdata = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

             if($title != $rowdata['website_title']) {
                  $title = $rowdata['website_title'] 
?>
               <h4 class="title-small folder_name">  <?php echo $rowdata ['website_title'];   ?> </h4>
<?php
             }
?>    
                    <a class="smalltext font_val" href="<?php echo DOCUMENT_URL.$filedata ['file_name'];  ?> "  target="_blank"  ><?php echo $filedata['document_name']; ?></a>
<?php
        }
    }        
}

?>
```